# how to get the phantomjs working for karma testrunner?

Tags: angularjs, windows, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run the karmatest runner with phantomJS in windows 7. This is the config file:

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html
// Generated on 2015-06-01 using
// generator-karma 0.8.3

module.exports = function (config) {
  'use strict';

  config.set({
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    //preprocessors: {
    //  'app/**/*.js': ['coverage']
    //},
    //
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],
      'app/**/*.js': ['coverage']
    },

    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '../',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [

      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
      'bower_components/angular-smart-table/dist/smart-table.min.js',
      'bower_components/underscore/underscore.js',
      'app/modules/**/*.js',
      'app/modules/app.js',
      'app/modules/config.js',
      //'../app/scripts_old/**/*.js',
      //  'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.spec.js'
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: [
      'PhantomJS'
    ],

    // Which plugins to enable
    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-chrome-launcher'
    ],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false,

    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DISABLE

    // Uncomment the following lines if you are using grunt's server to run the tests
    // proxies: {
    //   '/': 'http://localhost:9000/'
    // },
    // URL root prevent conflicts with the site root
    // urlRoot: '_karma_'
  });
};
```

I installed the karmaphantomjs launcher here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-phantomjs-launcher

I also set the phantomjs_bin environment variable to \phantomjs.exe

When I use the chromebrowser it works fine. How can I get it running for phantomJS?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Remove the `PHANTOMJS_BIN` environment variable
- Find the path to phantomjs via the `cmd` shell, then run:

  ```
  where phantomjs
  ```
- Copy the location to the the `PATH` environment variable by running `path`, then appending it to the list

> Because you can override the phantomjs_bin path using env, that meant if you did that it would try to run the phantomjs script thru phantomjs.exe, not node.exe. This was fixable but led to more codepaths and I prefered to par things back to a simpler solution.

**References**

- [karma phantomjs-launcher fix: Switched from launching phantomjs via node to ensuring that the .exe is always launched](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/pull/33)
- [karma phantomjs-launcher source: index.js](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/blob/master/index.js)